# After deploy to PythonAnyWhere get NoReverseMatch error

Tags: python, django

i'm trying the djangoGirls tutorial, and after doing the Extend Your Application, my site works just fine at local, on the http://127.0.0.1:8000/. But when i pull to the PythonAnyWhere and try to acess the site, i got the error NoReverseMatch, like the picture below:

[NoReverseMatch Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzrDc.png)

So i want to know if anyone have a idea of what i can do to solve the problem, because i try and can't do it. I have no idea how to make it work.

All my codes are similar to the tutorial, here they :

urls.py:

```
 from django.conf.urls import url
 from . import views

 urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^$', views.post_list),
     url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail),
 ]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post

# Create your views here.

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte = timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_lists.html', {'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null = True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

base.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
<head>
    <title>Django Girls blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1><a href="/">Django Girls Blog</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                {% block content %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

post_lists.html:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="post">
            <div class="date">
                {{ post.published_date }}
            </div>
            <h1><a href="{% url 'blog.view.post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
            <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

post_detail.html:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="post">
        {% if post.published_date %}
            <div class="date">
                {{ post.published_date }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The link to the project on github is github.com/lucasdaquina/my-first-blog

Sorry not put a link on that, i can't put more than one link yet.

If i need to put some other information necessary to help me, just let me now.
Thank you all for the help and attention.

Comment: Perhaps try reloading the server? I think it may cache python files, but not templates.

Answer (score 2):

As you follow the [Django Girls tutorial](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/extend_your_application/#create-a-url-to-a-posts-detail), you should get a `NoReverseMatch` error at first. It then shows you how to fix it.

First of all, the url tag should just have `'post_detail'`, not `'blog.view.post_detail'` as you have.

```
{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}"
```

Then, the tutorial gets you to add a name to your URL pattern to fix the error:

```
 url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail, name="post_detail"),
```